# Remove extra spaces and many tags using String.Replace() method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a long string containing the `&nbsp,<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> and <br>`. I want to clean my string from all these tags and spaces. How it can be done with String.Replace() method. I am doing separately right now, it is working but is there a way to do it at once, without replace() method.

```
String.Replace("&nbsp;","").Replace("<p>","").Replace("<br>","")
```

It is giving me clean code but I am looking for a general solution, means if I am having more tags (10 to 20) to filter then how to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace is good in all, you can have a list of tags and do as bellow:

```
foreach(var tag in tags)
{
   str = str.Replace(tag, "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a regex alternation pattern made up of all the tags to replace, such as `tag1|tag2`, and use the [`Regex.Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx). You should escape them to prevent any of the characters from being incorrectly interpreted as regex metacharacters.

For example:

```
string input = "<p>Hello,&nbsp;World<br>Foo<br>Bar</p>";
string[] replaceItems = { "<p>", "&nbsp;", "<br>" };
if (replaceItems.Length > 0)
{
    string pattern =
        String.Join("|", replaceItems.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)).ToArray());
    string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, String.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
else
{
    // nothing to replace
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

If you need the replacement to be case insensitive use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option: `Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`.

In .NET 4.0 you can drop the `ToArray()` call.

Comment: Regex may not be a easy solution but it surely is more extensible

Answer (score 1):

@ all the answers using replace on string, depending on the number of replacements its more efficient to use a StringBuilder since a string-object is immutable.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(input);

var replaceItems = new[] { "<p>", "&nbsp;", "<br>" };
foreach (var replace in replaceItems)
{
   sb.Replace(replace, String.Empty);
}

input = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just write an extension method to make it easy on the eyes - when using its now a one-liner.

```
string[] token = { "foo", "bar" };
string text = "blaah foo bar text";

text = text.ReplaceAll(token, "");


public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string ReplaceAll(this string text, 
                                    string[] token, 
                                    string replacement)
    {
        string newText = text;

        foreach (string s in token)
            newText = newText.Replace(s, replacement);

        return newText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] items= { "<p>", "&nbsp;", "<br>" };

foreach (string itemtodelete in items)
{
    test=test.Replace(itemtodelete,"");
}
```